# How to choose file based on position in shell ls list?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, terminal, script

Say we are using ubuntu's bash and we cd to the folder *myFolder*.

Now, say we use ls in this folder, and we get a list of files:

*file1*
*file2*
*file3*

We want to, for the sake of this example, run *file2* on node.

Is there a way to choose the file based on it's position on the ls list/ folder?
For example, something like `node "secondFileOfFolderHere"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
node "$(ls -1 | awk 'NR==2')"
```

`-1` switch lists one file per line; `awk` prints line 2

Comment: what does nr stands for?

Comment: Current record (i.e. line) number